# How to highlight an array of words in D3 word cloud

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, word-cloud, d3-cloud

I want to ***highlight*** a new array of words like "salmon" & "prey" that I want to provide to my word cloud, so how should I do it because I tried to use mark.js or Javascript with CSS but couldn't succeed, but now I think it is only possible here when I am drawing the word cloud. So can someone help me to provide me with a function or maybe some changes in my code to highlight the array (**arrayToBeHighlight**) of words:

```
var width = 750, height = 500;
var words = [["whales", 79], ["salmon", 56], ["Chinook", 30], ["book", 70],
["prey", 51]].map(function(d) {
    return {text: d[0], size: d[1]}; 
});

var arrayToBeHighlight = [ ["salmon", 56], ["prey", 51] ];
**OR**
var arrayToBeHighlight = ["salmon", "prey"];

maxSize = d3.max(words, function(d) { return d.size; });
minSize = d3.min(words, function(d) { return d.size; });

var fontScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([minSize, maxSize]).range([10,70]);

var fill = d3.scale.category20();
d3.layout.cloud().size([width, height]).words(words).font("Impact")
.fontSize(function(d) { return fontScale(d.size) })
.on("end", drawCloud).start();

function drawCloud(words) {
d3.select("#wordCloud").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2) + "," + (height / 2) +")")
  .selectAll("text")
    .data(words)
  .enter().append("text")
    .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size + "px"; })
    .style("font-family", "Impact")
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return fill(i); })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
    })
    .text(function(d) { return d.text; });
}
```

**HTML Code**

```
<div style="margin-left:20px" id="wordCloud"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things like `mark.js` work by creating a span around the word and setting a background color to mimic a highlighter.  This doesn't work in SVG because `text` elements don't have a background color.  Instead, you can fake it by inserting a `rect` before the text element:

```
  texts.filter(function(d){
    return arrayToBeHighlight.indexOf(d.text) != -1; 
  })
  .each(function(d){
    var bbox = this.getBBox(),
        trans = d3.select(this).attr('transform');
    g.insert("rect", "text")
      .attr("transform", trans)
      .attr("x", -bbox.width/2)
      .attr("y", bbox.y)
      .attr("width", bbox.width)
      .attr("height", bbox.height)
      .style("fill", "yellow");
  });
```

Running code;

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud/master/build/d3.layout.cloud.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="margin-left:20px" id="wordCloud"></div>
  <script>
    var width = 750,
      height = 500;
    var words = [
      ["whales", 79],
      ["salmon", 56],
      ["Chinook", 30],
      ["book", 70],
      ["prey", 51]
    ].map(function(d) {
      return {
        text: d[0],
        size: d[1]
      };
    });

    var arrayToBeHighlight = ["salmon", "prey"];

    maxSize = d3.max(words, function(d) {
      return d.size;
    });
    minSize = d3.min(words, function(d) {
      return d.size;
    });

    var fontScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([minSize, maxSize]).range([10, 70]);

    var fill = d3.scale.category20();
    d3.layout.cloud().size([width, height]).words(words).font("Impact")
      .fontSize(function(d) {
        return fontScale(d.size)
      })
      .on("end", drawCloud).start();

    function drawCloud(words) {
      var g = d3.select("#wordCloud").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2) + "," + (height / 2) + ")");
        
      var texts = g.selectAll("text")
        .data(words)
        .enter().append("text")
        .style("font-size", function(d) {
          return d.size + "px";
        })
        .style("font-family", "Impact")
        .style("fill", function(d, i) {
          return fill(i);
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
        })
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.text;
        });
        
      texts.filter(function(d){
        return arrayToBeHighlight.indexOf(d.text) != -1; 
      })
      .each(function(d){
        var bbox = this.getBBox(),
            trans = d3.select(this).attr('transform');
        g.insert("rect", "text")
          .attr("transform", trans)
          .attr("x", -bbox.width/2)
          .attr("y", bbox.y)
          .attr("width", bbox.width)
          .attr("height", bbox.height)
          .style("fill", "yellow");
      });
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot. That is exactly I needed :)

Comment: Couldn't you use mark.js with a custom element `rect`?

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on your definition of *highlight* and how you want to highlight them.

One possibility is comparing the `arrayToBeHighlight` array with the datum when painting the words. For instance, turning them red:

```
.style("fill", function(d, i) { 
    return arrayToBeHighlight.indexOf(d.text) > -1 ? "red" : fill(i); 
})
```

Here is the bl.ocks: http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/d38d1fbb5919c04783934d430fb895c2/b42582053b03b178bb155c2bbaec5242374d051b